# How apps like @macafee and other antivirus apps runs in background without enabling autostart in android

Tags: android, autostart

How these types of apps get location and perform other actions in Background without auto-start permission in phones like xiomi.

Answer (score 0):

Few popular apps run in background without being killed during memory cleanup cycle (many of the polular OEMs customize the stack ROM for battery/memory optimization), because they are "White listed" by these manufactures.

For your app you can whitelist it either manually (via corresponding "settings" for the devices) or pragmatically by redirecting users to the corresponding settings page to white list the app. Pragmatically you can do like below:

1. Add below permissions in the App's manifest file:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="oppo.permission.OPPO_COMPONENT_SAFE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.permission.external_app_settings.USE_COMPONENT"/>
   ```
2. Redirect your to the Auto Start setting:

   ```
   if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi")) {
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                       "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
               startActivity(intent);
           } else if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")) {
               Intent intent = new Intent();
               intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager",
                       "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
               startActivity(intent);
           } else if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("oppo")) {
               try {
                   Intent intent = new Intent();
                   intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                           "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                   startActivity(intent);
               } catch (Exception e) {
                   try {
                       Intent intent = new Intent();
                       intent.setClassName("com.oppo.safe",
                               "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity");
                       startActivity(intent);
                   } catch (Exception ex) {
                       try {
                           Intent intent = new Intent();
                           intent.setClassName("com.coloros.safecenter",
                                   "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity");
                           startActivity(intent);
                       } catch (Exception exx) {

                       }
                   }
               }
           }
   .... //Like for other OEMs [Check details for the devices here][1]
   ```

I have tested this method and it worked but the reliability is still a question.

But as an user we can prevent the app's background services as below :

1. Press Recent apps physical key (left side button).
2. Drag down the app once (select, hold & slide it down) which you require to be put in continuous operation.
3. The app will be put in lock condition (even if you clear the background app processes by clearing, the app will keep on running).
4. Same way, if you want to remove it from the lock condition, just drag down again once and the lock symbol will disappear (clearing the background process will clear the app from running too).

Comment: Reference for redirecting user to AutoStart settings pragmatically: https://tutel.me/c/programming/questions/48166206/how+to+start+power+manager+of+all+android+manufactures+to+enable+background+and+push+notification

Comment: @slfan Why I can't see the permissions listed under "Add below permissions in the App's manifest file" after u edited the answer? These permissions are required to handled crashes on few devices.